# By expressing $y = {u \over v}$ as $y = u{v^{ - 1}}$ prove the quotient rule

Tags: calculus

How do I go about doing this? I'm clueless..
Thank you.

My attempt:

Using the product rule and making:

$\eqalign{
  & u = u  \cr 
  & v = {v^{ - 1}} \cr} $

so:

${{du} \over {dx}} = 1$
and ${{dv} \over {dx}} =  - {v^{ - 2}}$
so:

$\eqalign{
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = u{{dv} \over {dx}} + v{{du} \over {dx}}  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = u( - {v^{ - 2}}) + {v^{ - 1}}(1)  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {v^{ - 2}}(v - u) \cr} $

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I think the question will be assuming that you know that product rule; given this, it should be reasonably straightforward.

Comment: @Assad You can not suppose $v=v^{-1}$ thus you make a restriction on $v$ which must be an arbitrary function.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about this? Why can't i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=u\frac{d(\frac1v)}{dx}+\frac{du}{vdx}$$
and 
$$\frac{d(\frac1v)}{dx}=-\frac{v'}{v^2}$$

then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-uv'}{v^2}+\frac{u'}{v}=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$

Comment: You wrote: $\frac{d(\frac1v)}{dx}=-\frac{v'}{v^2}$, why isn't this written as: ${{d({1 \over v})} \over {dx}} =  - {v^{ - 2}} = {{ - 1} \over {{v^2}}}$? Surely that's what it differentiates to? Why is v' on the numerator? Could you explain this please? Thank you.

Comment: @Assad because v is a function like $f(x)$ not a variable like $x$ ,so you should use the chain rule,$(u(v(x))'=u'(v(x))v'(x)$ wish i can help you understand the difference

Comment: Thank you! I see it now!

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)'=-\frac{v'}{v^2}$$
and $$(ut)'=u't+ut'$$
then we take $t=\frac{1}{v}$ and we find
$$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'}{v}-\frac{uv'}{v^2}=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this, could you look at my  answer and tell me what to do from there? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(uv^{-1})'=u'v^{-1}+u(v^{-1})'$$

**But**

$$(v^{-1})'=-\frac{v'}{v^2}\;,\;\;\text{so}\ldots$$